# how to sort by price with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello I am having a problem sorting products by price and this is my code. I am trying to sort product box but it's not working.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).on("change", ".price-sorting", function() {

    var sortingMethod = $(this).val();

    if(sortingMethod == 'l2h')
    {
        sortProductsPriceAscending();
    }
    else if(sortingMethod == 'h2l')
    {
        sortProductsPriceDescending();
    }

});
function sortProductsPriceAscending()
{
    var products = $('.product');
products.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("price")-$(b).data("price")});
$(".products-grid").html(products);

}

function sortProductsPriceDescending()
{
        var products = $('.product');
products.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("price") - $(a).data("price")});
$(".products-grid").html(products);
}
</script>
    </head>
 


    <body>
    <select class="price-sorting type-regular" name="price-sorting">
    <option selected disabled>Default</option>
    <option value="l2h">Low to high</option>
    <option value="h2l">High to low</option>
</select>

 <div class="flex-containershop products-grid">

        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#"  data-price="300"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">300$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#" data-price="6"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">6$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#" data-price="30"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">30$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#" data-price="20"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">20$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        

    
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(products)`. It is the dom element which you are trying to sort not the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some updates to your code.

You were not getting the price value but the nodes in the sort, so that couldn't be compared.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".price-sorting", function() {

    var sortingMethod = $(this).val();

    if(sortingMethod == 'l2h')
    {
        sortProductsPriceAscending();
    }
    else if(sortingMethod == 'h2l')
    {
        sortProductsPriceDescending();
    }

});

function getAmount(price){
  return parseFloat(price.replace('$', ''));
}


function sortProductsPriceAscending()
{
    var products = $('.productbox');
    products.sort(function(a, b){ return getAmount($(a).children('.price').text()) - getAmount($(b).children('.price').text()) });
    $(".products-grid").html(products);

}

function sortProductsPriceDescending()
{
    var products = $('.productbox');
    products.sort(function(a, b){ return getAmount($(b).children('.price').text()) - getAmount($(a).children('.price').text()) });
    $(".products-grid").html(products);

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <select class="price-sorting type-regular" name="price-sorting">
    <option selected disabled>Default</option>
    <option value="l2h">Low to high</option>
    <option value="h2l">High to low</option>
</select>

 <div class="flex-containershop products-grid">

        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#"  data-price="300"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">300$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#" data-price="6"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">6$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#" data-price="30"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">30$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        
    <div class="productbox">  <a href="#" data-price="20"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img></a>
        
        <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p> <p class="price" title="USD">20$</p>
        <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
    </div>
    
        

    
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function sortProductsPrice(dir) {
    var products = [];
    var par = $(".productbox:eq(0)").parent();
    $('.productbox').each(function(i, el) {
      products.push(el);
    });
    if (dir == "l2h") {
      products.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(".price", a).text()) - parseInt($(".price", b).text());
      });
    } else {
      products.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(".price", b).text()) - parseInt($(".price", a).text());
      });
    }
    par.html("");
    $.each(products, function(i, el) {
      par.append(el);
    });
  }

  $(document).on("change", ".price-sorting", function() {
    var method = $(this).val();
    if (method != 'default') {
      sortProductsPrice(method);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="price-sorting type-regular" name="price-sorting">
  <option selected disabled>Default</option>
  <option value="l2h">Low to high</option>
  <option value="h2l">High to low</option>
</select>
<div class="flex-containershop products-grid">
  <div class="productbox">
    <a href="#" data-price="300"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p>
    <p class="price" title="USD">300$</p>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <a href="#" data-price="6"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p>
    <p class="price" title="USD">6$</p>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <a href="#" data-price="30"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p>
    <p class="price" title="USD">30$</p>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <a href="#" data-price="20"> <img class="boximage" src="images/new%20design,jpeg.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Price:</p>
    <p class="price" title="USD">20$</p>
    <p class="procutboxtext">Color:<span class="white"></span> <span class="black"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

First, you should build an Array of Elements and then sort that array. Once sorted you have to redraw them in the proper order.

If you need to compare the Price, you need to get that value first. This can be done with `.text()`. To use it in evaluation or math, you should convert it to Integer.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing and fixing it. It is working and helped me to learn new things

Comment: @Elyasomer great! I hope you will want to upvote it if it helped or mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple things to note:

HTML elements load from top to bottom.  So with your script being placed in the `<head>` tag risks your event listener: `$(document).on("change", ".price-sorting"` is at risk of not actually being attached to the element.  See [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), or append your script to the *bottom of the page*.

Secondly, I noticed you weren't targeting an element that I could find on the page:
`$('.product')`, and you were also expecting `data-price` to be on the element you were targeting when in reality it was on the child anchor tag.

To fix your code I updated two things:

I put the `data-price` attribute on the parent element itself:

`<div class="productbox" data-price="300">` (for all of them, of course).

And targeted the productbox:

`var products = $('.productbox');`

And sorting functions as expected.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing changed the script place now it is in the bottom. The way you told I tried recently but unfortunately didn't worked but no problem already solved and thanks